# Ionic 4 -Angular : Blocked Youtube video “Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)”

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic4, cross-origin-read-blocking

In my **Ionic4-Angular** application, I’m trying to show a youtube video on my Modal page named ***activity-video.page.html***

```
<video>
    <source [src]="videoURL" />
</video>
```

My ***activity-video.page.ts*** looks like:

```
videoURL: string;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams, private modalController: ModalController) {
    this.videoURL = navParams.get("videoURL");
  }
```

No ERRORS but only a message in  Chrome DevTools :

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fqI-feIYfhY with MIME type text/html.
>   See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

I tried running Google Chrome this way: *chrome.exe --disable-web-security* but doesn't work

I tried a chrome extension to avoid CORB and also tried Chromium but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if this is the full solution but have you tried using the embed url not the watch url:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/fqI-feIYfhY

If that doesn't work I would try using the snippet in `share > embed` option of the YouTube page, instead of a direct `<video>` tag:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fqI-feIYfhY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You will need to Google making YouTube video's responsive, it's a solved problem.